# gitattribute end of line setting

Tags: git, github, gitattributes

I'm working on a code repository where all developers collaborating with the repository using windows PC & eclipse as their IDE. The repository administrator has setup this `.gitattributes` file in the parent directory with the following:

```
* text eol=crlf
```

I read [here](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) that git internally maintains object database to write(commit)/read(checkout) the changes.

Does this above setting in `.gitattributes` will checkout the code with CRLF(windows) line ending and the file in the repository will be maintained in CRLF?

Enabled the "Show White Spaces" option in Eclipse IDE revealed that all the file endings were line feed(LF) without carriage return(CR).

Could someone point out the cause of this behavior?

On a different repository, It has

```
* text eol=lf
*.java eol=crlf
*.csv eol=crlf
*.jar binary
*.sql eol=crlf
```

Does this mean all files(.java/.csv/.sql) would have CRLF and other files would have LF line endings?

Comment: Have you already read up on this?  Here is a good resource https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_text_code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good source for `.gitattributes` info are the gitscm.com docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_text_code)

1. I do not believe `* text eol=crlf` will work.  It should be `* text crlf`
2. You need to break the single line `* text eol=lf*.java eol=crlf*.csv eol=crlf*.jar binary*.sql eol=crlf` into the multiple lines.

Add these lines to your `. gitattributes` file.

```
# other files will have LF
* text=lf

# .java .csv .jar .sql will have CRLF
*.java eol=lf 
*.csv eol=crlf
*.jar eol=crlf
*.sql eol=crlf
```

Comment: I think you made a typo in the first bullet point: `* text=crlf` as in your example below!?