# Git messing up line endings despite .gitattributes

Tags: git, macos, gitattributes

I have already seen [gitattribute end of line setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496664/gitattribute-end-of-line-setting) and this is a different and quite bizarre problem.  I have already checked my autocrlf and eol configurations and they are not set

I'm on a Mac.  In our repository we have a .gitattributes file that looks like this:

```
*.sql text eol=lf
*.sh text eol=lf
```

This works perfectly for .sql files.  However we have a file named `scripts/some-version.SQL`.  It is checked in with Unix lf endings.  When I check it out on OS X, that file immediately gets converted to dos crlf endings and is marked as changed.  Checking the same file out on Windows gives a Unix lf ending.

If I comment out the `.sql` line in the .gitattributes file, I stop getting the .SQL file checked out as crlf.  It is the .gitattributes  that is causing this behavior.  However then Windows users will accidentally start checking in crlf endings again.  Changing the filename is sadly not an option.

I tried adding a `.SQL text eol=lf` line to .gitattributes but that did not help.

How can we have a .gitattributes for our Windows users without messing up the line endings for this file on OS X?

---

Per request.  A demonstration of the issue, along with `check-attr`.

```
macbookpro:postgres btilly$ git checkout scripts/
Updated 1 path from the index
macbookpro:postgres btilly$ git status scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL 
On branch integration
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/integration'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
macbookpro:postgres btilly$ git check-attr -a scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL 
scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL: text: set
scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL: eol: lf
macbookpro:postgres btilly$ file scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL 
scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Do you have some process monitoring your working tree?  An editor?  Some sort of service or script that's running in the background?  Are you on a case-insensitive or case-sensitive file system on your Mac?

Comment: @bk2204 No process is monitoring my working tree.  No services or scripts that I'm aware of.  The filesystem is APFS which remembers the case but does not allow 2 files whose names only differ by case.

Comment: Can you include in your question the output of `git check-attr -a scripts/some-version.SQL` as a code block?

Comment: @bk2204 I went a step farther and gave you that along with output demonstrating the whole problem.

Comment: say `git cat-file -p @:scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL | file -` to check that the file really is checked in with lf endings, git mishandling endings with just this one file is implausible.

Comment: @jthill I get `fatal: Not a valid object name @:scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL`.  What command did you mean?  Also digging farther it sadly has a mix of line endings.  Which is..messed up.

Comment: I was trying to retype the filename from your sample, but it looks like you found what I suspected. If the endings are mixed up enough just force-/re-adding the content won't get git to do it for you then you get to fix it yourself.

Comment: @jthill Then why is it only a problem on my system but not Windows?  Anyways this file is autogenerated so I can modify that.

Comment: The behavior should be the same on macOS and Windows, but perhaps whatever reads and writes `scripts/3.20.08-UPDATE.SQL` on Windows allows both LF and CRLF endings, while whatever reads and writes that file on macOS is touchier. Note that whatever is in existing commits (crlf-only, lf-only, or mixed) will still be in those existing commits, now and forevermore; only *future* commits and the copy in your working tree can be affected by `eol=` settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your file has been checked in with CRLF line endings, at least in some places.  Much to people's surprise, editing `.gitattributes` doesn't affect any files that are checked in to the repository already, and it doesn't affect clean files in the working tree.

Basically, anytime you make a change to `.gitattributes`, you need to run `git add --renormalize .` and commit those changes as well.  Otherwise, you can end up with things in an inconsistent state.

Note also that your `.gitattributes` pattern will not work on systems that are case sensitive, since your pattern uses the lower case `*.sql` and your file has the upper case `.SQL`.  So you'll probably want to add this as well:

```
*.SQL text eol=lf
```

Of course, you'll want to do that before running `git add --renormalize .`.

Comment: "Much to people's surprise, editing .gitattributes doesn't affect any files that are checked in ..., and it doesn't affect clean files in the working tree." In case you were being snarky: people aren't surprised about *that*, of course. The surprise stems (quite naturally) from the counter-intuitive fact that `.gitattributes` does not directly control *the behavior of handling those files* (regardless of what line endings are checked in and what line endings are in the work tree).